# Matplotlib - can't plot a simple line (y=mx+b)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a simple line in Matplotlib. I have already added elements to make a scatter plot, and now, I'm just trying to add a straight line in it.

Here's my code:

```
data = (g1, g2, g3)
colors = ("red", "green", "blue")
groups = ("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")

# Create plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, facecolor='white')

for data, color, group in zip(data, colors, groups):
    x, y = data
    ax.scatter(x, y, alpha=1, c=color, edgecolors='none', s=50, label=group)

plt.title('Scatter plot')
plt.xlabel('Petal width')
plt.ylabel('Petal length')

x = np.linspace(0,5,2)
y = -3.84*x+5
plt.plot(x, y, '-r', label='y=2x+1')

plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Gives me this:

[image]

- Why is there a white space with nothing in the Y-coordinates ?
- I would like this line to go from (0, 5) to (1.3, 0).

Thanks

EDIT. Ive just converted all my points to floats and now my plot looks like this, how do I make it so the points are evenly placed on the plot?

[image]

Comment: Is your scatter plot meant to look like that (ignoring the line for a second)? If you look at both the x and y axis tick labels you can see they are not ordered. Probably because your data are strings..

Comment: For the  `x` of the line use `np.linspace(0, 5, 2, endpoint=True)`.

Comment: For the scatter plot you need to convert all coordinates from text to float. It is unclear in which exact format `g1, g2, g3` are. But `x = [float(xi) for xi in x]` could work in most cases.

Comment: Hi, my scatter plot is correct, my question is about how to draw the straight line on top of it. The white space appears when I try to add the straight line.

Comment: I've just converted all the points to floats and now, theres another problem. Please look at my edit. Thanks

Comment: If you label the red line `"y=2x+1"` then why do you plot the line `y = -3.84*x+5` ?

Comment: Yeah that's just a legend mistake